# Unable to upload tests cases from excel to Azure Dev Ops

Tags: excel, testing, import, devops

I am trying to import a large amount of test cases from excel into azure dev ops however the option to import does not appear. Is this an add on that is missing from azure as other azure dev ops appear to have it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmo4W.png)

i have tried the the query option which should show import work items but the option is not there for me